# Bayesian estimation of weighted proportion

Tags: bayesian, inference, proportion, beta-binomial-distribution

Having bayesian estimates of a proportion is relatively easy. You model that proportion as a binomial variable, you choose a beta-binomial prior and by using the likelihood you obtain a beta-binomial posterior.

I have problems providing bayesian estimates of a weighted proportion. That is, I wont to compute estimates of the variable:
$$p' = (\sum w*success)/\sum w $$ instead of 
$$p = (\sum success)/n$$
I don't even know if I need to provide a distribution of the weighting variable, but if I had to I would choose a normal distribution.

Is there a way to use bayesian inference to estimate the distribution of p'?

Comment: Could you give us more details on what is your actual data? What is the meaning of the weights?

Comment: Weights are shopping carts of my customers and successes happen when a customer actually buys. So it's like a conversion metric weighted towards the amount of the shopping cart

Comment: Attempting to state an auxiliary variable as a weight doesn't seem to be optimal.  I'd like to see a fully specified model with parameters for each quantity of interest.  Then standard Bayesian modeling should be possible.

Comment: As described $p$ is the transform of observations, not a parameter. To run Bayesian analysis for this case, you need to specify the distribution of $p$, or of the observations behind.